# scp: why "Name or service not known" has priority over "No such file or directory"?

Tags: linux, scp

Consider:

```
$ file xxx
xxx: cannot open `xxx' (No such file or directory)
```

Then why:

```
$ scp xxx user@xxx.xx
ssh: Could not resolve hostname xxx.xx: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

instead of:

```
$ scp xxx user@xxx.xx
xxx: cannot open `xxx' (No such file or directory)
```

If there is no such file or directory, then why trying to connect in the first place?

Is it a bug in `scp`'s logic?

Comment: It has to check both error cases at some time. It is arbitrary which the developer chose to do first. Possibly the transfer would be initiated after a time-stamp check, in which case it should not modify the access time on the file before checking out other causes for aborting.

Answer (score 4):

It's a result of the order in which `scp` does things. The sequence is roughly:

1. Open connection to remote computer
2. Send/receive first file
3. Send/receive second file
4. ...etc...
5. Close connection

Since it'll discover a problem with the connection at step 1, it'll error out at that point before it's gotten around to doing anything with the files.

It'd be possible for it to pre-check the files before making the connection (for sending only -- when receiving, it logically *has* to make the connection first), but that's an extra step and actually makes error handling more complex, because there's the additional error situation where a file vanishes between the pre-check and when it's actually sent.

Comment: What about this pre-check logic: `if (op == SEND && all_files_in_list_do_not_exist ) { for ( all_files_in_list ) error(f, "No such file or directory"); exit(1); }`?

Comment: @pmor It could do that, but there's no real need to, and it'd complicate the error handling (it'd *still* need to handle the situation where there's an error when it goes to send the file). So why bother?

Comment: No real need to open connection to remote computer if all files in list do not exist. Because there is nothing to send. Why bother: to make the logic correct, to eliminate unnecessary connections.

Comment: It makes no sense to go to the post if there is no letter to send. It makes no sense to call 911 if there is nothing to report.

Comment: To speed-up: the `all_files_in_list_do_not_exist` can be replaced with `! at_least_one_file_in_list_exists`.

Comment: The logic's correct as it is: one error has to override the other, and neither one is particularly more correct than the other. Or, to put it another way, why does it matter if the files exist when you can't connect to the other computer? Also, changing it'd make it inconsistent with receiving, where the connection error *must* take precedence over a file-doesn't-exist error.

Comment: @pmor  So then you would demand an option to say "Send any files you can" or "These files are a set -- only send them if all of them exist", or even ".. if more than 60% of them exist". If it matters, you could write your own pre-check, or design your system so it does not ask to send files that it has not got. `scp` has a valid logic: make sure you have a route map *before* you load all the kids into the car.

Comment: @GordonDavisson _when you can't connect to the other computer?_: good point, thanks! I think that with the "post analogy" above there is no need to check whether the letter exists in case if it is known _in advance_ that the post is closed. If it is not known _in advance_ that the post is closed, then there is need to check first whether the letter exists. With `scp` it is not known in advance whether connection to remote computer can be established. Hence, there is a need to check first whether at least one of the files from the list exists. What is your view on that?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant The intent is to go to trip with the kids. If none of the kids is there, then the intent cannot be accomplished: there is no trip and there is no need to check for a route map. So, first you check whether at least one (or all, depending on your policy) of the kids is there.

Comment: @pmor I still don't see why you think there's a "need" to check whether the files exist first. You (I hope) generally don't tell `scp` to copy nonexistent files, and if you do occasionally goof and tell it to, making a useless `ssh` connection is not a big deal. If you have something like an automated script that tries to send a maybe-existent file, I'd say it's the script's responsibility to check the file's status before it tells `scp` to do something that doesn't make sense.